# Function to set axis labels only partially works, how do I get the axis labels to display as a function

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I want to write a function that will print the title and x and y labels.  I managed to get the title to display but my code does not display the axis labels.

```
def title(t, y, x):
    return ax.set_title(t)
    ax.set_ylabel(y) 
    ax.set_xlabel(x)
```

I expect the code to display the Title, y-axis label, and x-axis label
I enter the function like this:

```
title('LKJH', 'gg', 'ff')
```

I get the following chart instead
[image: Chart that is produced from code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function title you have used return statement only for `ax.set_title`. The function is not considering the last 2 statements.
You have to use comma (,) separator after every value if returning multiple values.

```
def title(t, y, x):
return (ax.set_title(t), ax.set_ylabel(y), ax.set_xlabel(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You were only returning `set_title` as a result the labels were not displaying.

Return all configs like this:

```
def title(t, y, x):
    return ax.set_title(t), ax.set_ylabel(y), ax.set_xlabel(x)
```